# ESLint restrict using React.StatelessComponent and React.FunctionalComponent

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, eslintrc, typescript-eslint

Is there a rule where in I can disable usage of `React.StatelessComponent` or `React.FunctionalComponent` to use only `React.FC`

For example:

```
export const ComponentOne: React.StatelessComponent<Props> = (props) => { return <....> };
export const ComponentTwo: React.FunctionalComponent<Props> = (props) => { return <....> };
```

Should be enforced by ESLint to be written as

```
export const ComponentOne: React.FC<Props> = (props) => { return <....> };
export const ComponentTwo: React.FC<Props> = (props) => { return <....> };
```

I think it's possible via `no-restricted-syntax` rule but can't figure out from the documentation.

Comment: I don't think I have came across such a rule before. It is unlikely `eslint-plugin-react` will have such a rule as they do not have any language specific linting rules, such as TypeScript. The closes bet would be to add your own `no-restricted-syntax` rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok was finally able to figure it out, can achieve this using the rule `@typescript-eslint/ban-types`

```
"@typescript-eslint/ban-types": ["error",
{
    "types": {
        "React.StatelessComponent": { "message": "Please use React.FC instead.", "fixWith": "React.FC" },
        "React.FunctionalComponent": { "message": "Please use React.FC instead.", "fixWith": "React.FC" },
     }
   }
]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are enforcing `React.FC`? It seems to be suggested that we should not be using it at all - https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react#function-components , https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177 , https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-write-a-react-component-in-typescript

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about these articles, I wasn't aware of it. It was a personal preference for `FC` and not `FunctionalComponent`

Comment: No worries, I actually found your answer useful - but for the inverse, we plan to ban the usage of `React.FC` and I was looking for an ESLint rule that could help, so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

How to ban `React.FC` (why? https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177):

```
'@typescript-eslint/ban-types': [
  'error',
  {
    types: {
      'React.FC':
        'Useless and has some drawbacks, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177',
      'React.FunctionComponent':
        'Useless and has some drawbacks, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177',
      'React.FunctionalComponent':
        'Preact specific, useless and has some drawbacks, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/8177'
    }
  }
],
```

- [`React.StatelessComponent` and `React.SFC` have been removed from `@types/react` >= 18](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/56210/files#diff-32cfd8cb197872bcba371f5018185d2e75fa540b52cda2dd7d8ac12dcc021299L532-L547)
- [`React.VoidFunctionComponent` and `React.VFC` are deprecated](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/59882) and will eventually be removed (thus no need to ban them via ESLint)
- [`React.FunctionalComponent` is specific to Preact](https://github.com/preactjs/preact/blob/10.16.0/src/index.d.ts#L94)